# View does not update UIElement property

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a MainView with TabControl, which is intended to display child Views, and a ComboBox to display some values
MainView has this XAML:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelsCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding ViewModelsSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>

<ComboBox x:Name="cmbProfiles"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProfileCollection}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ProfileSelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Key">
</ComboBox>
```

Also, MainView has DataTemplates for child Views - to be used in the TabControl:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:OrdersViewModel}">
        <v:OrdersView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ShippingViewModel}">
        <v:ShippingView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

ChildViews are created in MainViewModel:

```
ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> collection = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>();

collection.Add(new OrdersViewModel());
collection.Add(new ShippingViewModel());

this.ViewModelsCollection = collection;
```

Each ChildView has a button, which IsEnabled property should depend on MainView's cmbProfiles selection:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=BtnServiceSetupIsEnabled}"
        Content="Next ...">
</Button>
```

Code in MainView to handle that:

```
IOrdersViewModel ordersViewModel = (IOrdersViewModel)this.ViewModelsCollection.Where(x => x.GetType().Equals(typeof(OrdersViewModel))).FirstOrDefault();

if (profileItem.Key == "Custom")
{
    ordersViewModel.BtnServiceSetupIsEnabled = true;
}
else
{
    ordersViewModel.BtnServiceSetupIsEnabled = false;
}
```

The problem occurs when I change selection in cmbProfiles: ChildViewModel.BtnServiceSetupIsEnabled gets updated in code indeed, but the ChildView doesn't reflect that change, button stays disabled.
It does work fine if I don't use DataTemplates and simply add <v:OrdersView/> to my MainView, not dynamically filling the TabControl.
How can I fix that - and to have my TabControl's TabItems created dynamically?

Comment: Are you sure that the view models in `ViewModelsCollection` are used as the data context of your tabs, actually? If you have the view model locator active, it might well overwrite the data context...

Comment: @Haukinger Yes, Im sure - added some other TextBlock in OrdersView, a property for it in VM, to set its text = "100" and the View displays "100"

Comment: From the code you've shown, it's impossible to know the cause of the problem. It would be better if you upload your Solution (or its minimum demo version) to GitHub and give a link to the repository.

Comment: @EldHasp + Haukinger, sorry, Im a bit lost now. I have it working now by just deleting `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"` from ChildViews. Otherwise, every time a TabItem becomes active - new ChildViewModel is created

Comment: Using the view model locator is great when you go view first, but *only* then. One shouldn't habitually add it to each and every view... in fact, in my experience, 90% of the views don't use it. View first is fine for navigating top level pages, but everything below has the management of child view models directly in the parent view model.